# save dummy image to FirebaseStorage flutter for user update them later after sign up

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage

i have both upload image method to firebasestorage and update image from firebasestorage.

but in my case i want a tameplate dummy image link create when sign up without user input so when user edit their profile they have empty background image. any suggestion how to make it?

Answer (score 1):

while signing up the user send empty string into image key and in the edit image option check that image key whether it is empty or not, if it is empty then show a demo image from project asset fold or from network image or if image is already there then show that image as it is.

Comment: Thankyou @Shubhanshu Kashiva, yes i thought of that too